# Sort hashSet by two conditions

Tags: java, guava

I want to sort a below categories by **name** and **place categories with ids: -1, 0 in begin**.

```
public class Category {
    Long id;
    String name;

    public Category(Long id, String name) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }    
}

Set<Categories> categories = new HashSet<>;
categories.add(new Category(2,"Drama"))
categories.add(new Category(-1,"Favorites"))
categories.add(new Category(3,"Cartoons"))
categories.add(new Category(1,"Biography"))
categories.add(new Category(0,"All"))
```

**How get such list?**

```
[{-1,"Favorites"}, {0,"All"}, {3,"Cartoons"}, {1,"Drama"}, {2,"Historical"}]
```

P.S. I have **Guava** lib

Comment: We don't do core writing requests here. Describe problem you are facing when you try writing your code and we will try help you solve it.

Comment: You should implement `hashCode` and `equals` in your `Category` class if you're storing instances in a `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a list and sort it:

```
Collections.sort(categories, (a, b) -> {
    if (a.id != b.id) {
        if (a.id == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b.id == -1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.id == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b.id == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a TreeSet instead of a HashSet and let Category implement Comparable (and implement compareTo as you wish). TreeSet will store a sorted set of your Category objects.

```
public class Category implements Comparable<Category>
{
  private final int id;
  private final String name;

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public Category(int id, String name)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }



  @Override
  public int compareTo(Category category)
  {
    return this.getId() - category.getId();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Set<Category> categories = new TreeSet<>();
    categories.add(new Category(2, "Drama"));
    categories.add(new Category(-1, "Favorites"));
    categories.add(new Category(3, "Cartoons"));
    categories.add(new Category(1, "Biography"));
    categories.add(new Category(0, "All"));

    for (Category category : categories)
    {
      System.out.println(category.getId());
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a problem with your code. HashSet checks whether the object is already there by first checking object's hashCode() and then by assuring it's the same object by calling equals(). If you do not define these two functions, all your Category objects are going to be different, no matter what values you put in them.

Secondly, to sort object you better make them comparable by implementing 
 Comparable< Category>

Finally, HashSet does not keep any order of the objects inside. If you use TreeSet instead of HashSet, you will get the order naturally.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet does not have Ordered Set.

If you want Ordered Set, you has use java.util.TreeSet.

to use java.util.TreeSet you must change Category for implements java.lang.Comparable and you implements method compareTo for provide comparation method or you java.util.Comparator in the java.util.TreeSet Constructor.

Sample with Comparator:

Usage:

```
Set<Category> categories = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Category>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Category o1, Category o2) {
        return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
    }
});
categories.add(new Category(2, "Drama"));
categories.add(new Category(-1, "Favorites"));
categories.add(new Category(3, "Cartoons"));
categories.add(new Category(1, "Biography"));
categories.add(new Category(0, "All"));
```

Sample with Comparable:

Category.java

```
public class Category implements Comparable<Category> {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Category o) {
        return id.compareTo(o.id);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
Set<Category> categories = new TreeSet<>();
categories.add(new Category(2, "Drama"));
categories.add(new Category(-1, "Favorites"));
categories.add(new Category(3, "Cartoons"));
categories.add(new Category(1, "Biography"));
categories.add(new Category(0, "All"));
```